# Pex and TestCategory

Tags: testing, pex

Is there any way to get Pex to decorate the test methods that it generates with the TestCategory attribute?  I've scoured the documentation (and all public classes) and don't see anything.

I know that I can manually add this attribute to the generated tests, but if I were then to re-run Pex Exploration, those manual changes would be lost.

Thanks in advance for any information.

David Mullin
IMA Technologies